# JAVA, interpolate n times the same variable with String.format

Tags: java, string, format, interpolation, string-interpolation

I would like to interpolate the same variables n times using String.format method.

For example with

```
String value = "hi";
String interpolated = String.format(" %s %s %s %s ", value);
```

I expect

```
System.out.println(interpolated)
// " hi hi hi hi "
```

Comment: Try `String.format(" %s %s %s %s ", value, value, value, value)`

Comment: You can try using a for-loop as well.

Comment: @Daniele isn't there cleaner way?

Answer (score 1):

You could do that (while harcoded in terms of occurrence):

```
String value = "hi";

String interpolated = String.format(" %s %s %s %s ", IntStream.range(0, 4)
                                                              .mapToObj(i -> value)
                                                              .toArray());
```

You could variabilize it in this way :

```
 public String repeat(String string, int nbRepeat){
    return String.format(" " + IntStream.range(0, nbRepeat)
                                         .mapToObj(i -> "%s")
                                         .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")),
                          IntStream.range(0, nbRepeat)
                                   .mapToObj(
                                           i -> string)
                                   .toArray());
}
```

And use it :

```
repeat("hi", 4);
repeat("ho", 6);
```

Answer (score 1):

> ..Isn't there cleaner way?

Well it depends on how you want to use it; if you want to avoid streams, you can use any of the below:

```
package sample;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class JoinString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] v = {"hi","hi","hi","hi"};
        System.out.println(String.join(" ", v));
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(v));
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
        System.out.println( formatter.format("%1$1s %1$1s %1$1s", "hi"));
        formatter.close();
        System.out.format("%1$1s %1$1s %1$1s %n", "hi"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify argument positions for the format tokens, in this case you would use the same position for all tokens:

```
String interpolated = String.format(" %1$s %1$s %1$s %1$s ", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 11 you can use [`repeat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) method like:

```
String value = "hi ";
System.out.println(value.repeat(nTimes));
```

To get interpolated string you can also use [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) class:

```
String interpolated = MessageFormat.format("{0}, {0}, {0}", "hi")
```

Comment: i need interpolation to using that string, not for printing only

Comment: @tommasoballardini Updated with `MessageFormat.format` method

Answer (score 0):

You can use below snippet :

```
String s = "hi";
    int n = 9;
    String interpolated  = String.format("%0"+ n +"d", 0).replace("0", s );
    System.out.println(interpolated );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop. refer below code.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter word : ");
    String str = sc.next();
    System.out.println("times : ");

    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i =0 ; i < n; i++){
        System.out.print(String.format("%s ", str));
    }
```